# set the format of the scrapyd output file

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I am using scrapy to collect data. Running spiders using scrapyd. The file with the results is added by default to

> /data/scrapyd/items/ {spider_name }/ {job_id }.jl

job_id - Installs scrapyd. Please tell me if it is possible to manually specify the title instead of job_id?

Answer (score 0):

curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=project_name -d spider=spider_name -d jobid=custom_jobid